# read CSV file with multiple choices separated with "

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file with Python, however, I am having a problem with splitting the columns, here is an example:

| CSV file |
| --- |

```
2011-04-15,Aleppo,Jebel Saman,Aleppo,36.202778,37.158611,cereals and tubers,"Bread (bakery, parallel market)",1.1 KG,actual,SYP,12.69,0.01    
2011-04-15,Aleppo,Jebel Saman,Aleppo,36.202778,37.158611,cereals and tubers,Maize (local),KG,actual,SYP,30.0,0.02
```

the problem in column 8 that has ("), it is not splitting into columns using the following code :

```
df = pd.read_csv("Syrian Arab Republic - Food Prices.csv")
```

the rest of the columns are fine:

[image: this the output]

[the dataset](https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hdx-production-filestore/resources/0819dc1a-4e91-44ac-956b-f93af8fd3fe5/wfp_food_prices_syr.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAXYC32WNARK756OUG&Expires=1635796453&Signature=gY3Oa0pmRSO4%2FMdO4lz6Zyj5ILE%3D)

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the `quotechar` parameter of `read_csv`.

Comment: The quotes mean the whole string is the contents of one column (i.e. commas in quoted string are not delimiters).

Comment: Dear @martineau, 

Thank you, but how can I read the file, I tried this code, but it is not working as well :(

df = pd.read_csv("Syrian Arab Republic - Food Prices.csv",quotechar='"', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)

Best,

Comment: Sorry, I'm no pandas expert. What you have looks OK (although the last two only apply when writing a CSV file, not when reading it). The CSV data ub the file looks very standard, so you shouldn't need to specify any formatting parameters.